# Is there an API for ocean temperatures?

Tags: xml, api, weather

I've checked all of the questions here about weather API's and checked every single suggested API but still no luck! I need an API that includes the water temperature in its response.

I'm using [wunderground](http://wiki.wunderground.com/index.php/API_-_XML) to get the weather forecast data I need, but I'm still missing the water temperature.

Is there an API (preferably free) that includes water temperature in its response? (I don't even mind if it's all that it sends back).

Comment: I have to ask, water temperature of what?  (How is this related to the weather? What is the water temperature in Phoenix, AZ for example?)

Comment: Could you possibly mean the wet-bulb temperature ?

Comment: Water temperature of the sea..it's a weather info mainly related to coastal cities. I need it for diving sites related pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it!
http://www.sea-temperature.com!

It doesn't offer a very flexible way to fetch the data and not all of the cities I want are there but It's better than nothing.

Hope this helps anyone who wants the same data.

Comment: But they don't have an API. Do they?

Comment: They don't, I remember parsing the HTML of the page and looking for the data I needed. Not the fanciest way but it's what got the job done back then.

Comment: Scrapey-scrapey

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Meteomatics Weather & Ocean API: [api.meteomatics.com](https://api.meteomatics.com)

It contains wave data, ocean currents, salinity, swell, tidal data, wind, hurricane data etc.

Answer (score 1):

The [National Oceanographic Data Center](http://www.nodc.noaa.gov/dsdt/index.html) has the information you're looking for in the United States.

The [European Environment Agency](http://www.eea.europa.eu/themes/coast_sea/todays-sea-surface-temperature/todays-sea-surface-temperature) has the information you're looking for in Europe.  I found a map but not an RSS feed.

Comment: Thanks for the link =) But I need it for the Middle East..specifically the Red sea and the Mediterranean Sea..